# How to do a permanent redirect in blogspot.com?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

What are the ways to do 301 redirect without .htacess file...

The problem at hand is that I have custom domain blogspot.com which I want to migrate to another domain, self hosted site... How do I do a 301 redirect in blogger custom domain?

The link structure is as follows:

the link structure of blogger site:
`somesite.blogspot.com/03/11/some-article.html`

blogger custom domain
`example.com/03/11/some-article.html`

new domain (self hosted) where I want to migrate:
`newdomain.com/some-article`

Comment: Hello Chirag, how have you solved this?

Comment: I did it by adding some javascript to Blogger HTML. Read more here: http://blogtimenow.com/blogging/automatically-redirect-blogger-blog-another-blog-website/

Answer (score 0):

**Add a CNAME (Alias) record points to an A (Host) record.**

I had a domain bought in godaddy.com, "desarrollolibre.org" and was trying Open Shift from Red Hat and I created a wordpress site there, and they gave me an url like redhat-cloud/myapp.com ... I wanted to show that wordpress blog but with my personalozed domain ... adding CName on desarrollolibre.org plus some config (add an alias on my rehat wordpress app)  worked for me.

**What this made was: rendered redhat-cloud/myapp.com but you could still see desarrollolibre.org in the browser's url.**

This docs I read when doing that and got it working in an hour:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Best regards.